# Javascript Plugin Noty doesn't work on Button Click

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am very new to JQuery. I want to implement Stack Overflow style notification on top of my page. So for that matter, I downloaded a JQuery plugin from [NOTY](https://github.com/needim/noty)
. I have read the tutorial but it doesn't explain how to implement this properly. All I want is to display the top notification on a button click. I have imported all the .js files as mentioned in the tutorial but can't figure out how to show the bar whenever i click a button.

Not just the NOTY plug in mentioned earlier, i don't know how to use .js files on button click for any plugin available on the net.

Can somebody please help?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
     <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.noty.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/top.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

Now what to write in the button click event?

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Please post your code so we'll something to refer to...

Comment: Please check the edited version

Comment: This is a server side Click event!

Comment: @ronen I understand that, but how do I get it to work. Obviously, when I want to notify a user, i will have to use server side code, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer this [documentation](http://needim.github.com/noty/)  for the noty usage

on the button click write this code

```
  var noty = noty({text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!'});
```

Comment: I have already done that as mentioned in the question. I can't figure out how to implement it on a button click.

Comment: errors are thrown... It wont accept the code that you sent. It says 'Invalid Expression Term'

Comment: what error is thrown. It's not a problem whether u accept or not.

Comment: This is a server side Click event!  but you are trying to use the client side plugin.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23283/discussion-between-athar-anis-and-muthu)

Comment: yes but how would i notify the user that the operation he performed was successful?

Comment: It's not a jquery issue. Change your question  to notify the success message in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some example here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.noty.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="top.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="default.js"></script>
<script>
function myNoty()
{
    var n = noty({
        text: 'hello',
        type: 'success',
      dismissQueue: true,
        layout: 'top',
        theme: 'defaultTheme'
    })

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="myNoty();" value="Click!"/>
</body>
</html>
```

change the options for your needs.

Comment: nothing happens when i click the button. I have implemented just as you showed.

Comment: Is it because It is a child page?

Comment: change the path of the scripts to your locations, this is probably the problem.

Comment: thats what i did. but still no luck. when i checked the javascript console in Chrome it says 'unCaught SyntaxError: unexpected Token <' on these files 1) jquery.noty.js (2) top.js (3) default.js.... and when i click the button it throws this error. 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function '

Comment: check your JS files, i think you didn't download them correctly.